# Set workbench_access taxonomy term to active

Tags: workbench

We're using workbench_access to separate content by taxonomy and when my customer adds a new term and tries to assign a role to it, is unable to find it in the list under admin/config/workbench/access/roles

To solve issues with permissions we've opted to set the module to "Generate automatic URL alias". When we create the term, that option is selected and unavailable as expected by this doc page:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1171382

I've cleared the cache and can see my new term in the admin/structure/taxonomy/myterm page.

It appears that the module in the auto mode is filtering using the workbench_access_editors() function which shows it in the list but not under the "active" flag, so it does not appear in the workbench role page.

I've looked and searched but it's not clear how to get this taxonomy term to be "active" so workbench can automatically load this term?